# Как разместить элементы TableLayout равномерно на весь экран?

Tags: java, android

Использую этот код, и получается такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void GrdidGenerate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LevelGrid[pos]; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        for (int j = 0; j < LevelGrid[pos]; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100 / LevelGrid[pos],
                    100 / LevelGrid[pos], 1);
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
        }
        grid.addView(tableRow, i);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы колонки растягивались на всю длину и не вылезали за поля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, так:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
```

Comment: Отметьте ваш ответ, как верный (нажмите на серую галку слева от сообщения)

Comment: @pavlofff , через пять часов только смогу)